# Improving performance of protocol buffers

Tags: java, optimization, protocol-buffers

I'm writing an application that needs to deserialize quickly millions of messages from a single file.

What the application does is essentially to get one message from the file, do some work and then throw away the message. Each message is composed of ~100 fields (not all of them are always parsed but I need them all because the user of the application can decide on which fields he wants to work on).

In this moment the application consists in a loop that in each iteration just executes using a `readDelimitedFrom()` call.

Is there a way to optimize the problem to fit better this case (splitting in multiple files, etc...). In addition, in this moment due to the number of messages and the dimension of each message, I need to gzip the file (and it is fairly effective in reducing the size since the value of the fields are quite repetitive) - this though reduces the performance.

Comment: can't you replace the loop with a multithreaded processing model?

Comment: I avoided to say this, but is is already multithreaded. Essentially the file is splitted in a certain number of slices and each thread works on a slice. The loop I describe in the question is actually the work of a single thread

Comment: Could you provide some additional information about the application's architecture? At first glance, I would think file I/O would be your major bottleneck and I am curious as to how the file is split into slices and how each of the threads is accessing their file slice.

Comment: the splitting is external compared to the application. Each thread starts, pick 1 slice and works on it producing an independent output - nothing is shared between the threads in term of structure. The threads are assigned the slice they have to work on when they are launched.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If CPU time is your bottleneck (which is unlikely if you are loading directly from HDD with cold cache, but could be the case in other scenarios), then here are some ways you can improve throughput:

- If possible, use C++ rather than Java, and reuse the same message object for each iteration of the loop.  This reduces the amount of time spent on memory management, as the same memory will be reused each time.
- Instead of using `readDelimitedFrom()`, construct a single `CodedInputStream` and use it to read multiple messages like so:

  ```
  // Do this once:
  CodedInputStream cis = CodedInputStream.newInstance(input);

  // Then read each message like so:
  int limit = cis.pushLimit(cis.readRawVarint32());
  builder.mergeFrom(cis);
  cis.popLimit(limit);
  cis.resetSizeCounter();
  ```

  (A similar approach works in C++.)
- Use Snappy or LZ4 compression rather than gzip.  These algorithms still get reasonable compression ratios but are optimized for speed.  (LZ4 is probably better, though Snappy was developed by Google with Protobufs in mind, so you might want to test both on your data set.)
- Consider using [Cap'n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/) rather than Protocol Buffers.  <s>Unfortunately, there is no Java version yet, but</s> EDIT: There is [capnproto-java](https://github.com/dwrensha/capnproto-java) and also implementations in many other languages. In the languages it supports it has been shown to be quite a bit faster.  (Disclosure:  I am the author of Cap'n Proto.  I am also the author of Protocol Buffers v2, which is the version Google released open source.)

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the majority of the time spent by your CPU is in garbage collection. I would look to replace the default garbage collector with one better suited for your use case of short lived objects.

If you do decide to write this in C++ - use an Arena to create the first message before parsing: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/arenas