# Java protobuf creating too many objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, protocol-buffers

I have a jetty server proxyfying betweena backend and converting protobufs frontend.proto->backend.proto and backend.proto->frontend.proto.

Requests take below 20ms(99th) and 40ms(99.9th) while load is not peaking.
However, when load peaks, the 99th increases +10 but the 99.9th increases by +60.

I have investigated it and the delayed requests are caused by GC Evacuation pauses, this I am sure of, this pauses take 50-70ms and run once every 15 seconds on valley load but jump up to once every 3-5 seconds on peak load, the duration is the same.
As soon as the GC frequency goes below 8-9 seconds the 99.9th percentile shoots up and I can see the debug logs of slow requests concurrently with the GC log.

I have profiled with JProfiler, Yourkit and VisualVM and saw that:

- Eden space fills up and a GC pause is triggered
- Very few of the objects are moved into Survivor(few MB out of 12G)
- So most of the objects are already expired in Eden
- This makes sense since requests take 30-40ms and most of the objects lifetime is tied to the request lifetime
- Most of the objects are created during protobuf deserialization time

I've tried playing with GCPauseMillis and Eden sizes but nothing seems to make a difference, it never takes less than 50ms and bigger Eden means less frequency but much longer pauses

I see 2 options here:

1. Somehow reuse object creation in java-protobuf: Seems impossible, read through a lot of posts and mails and its not setup that way, they just say that "Java object allocation is very efficient and it should be able to handle many objects being created", and while that is true, the associated GC cost is killing my 99.9th
2. Make the GC run more often, say once a second, to bring collection time down so that it will stop more requests but for shorter times: I have been playing with GCMaxMillis and Eden sizes but I can't seem to get it lower than that

I uploaded the gc log to [gc_log](https://filebin.ca/4ZLlgxKmA0LN)

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

GC details:

```
-XX:CICompilerCount=12 -XX:ConcGCThreads=5 -XX:ErrorFile=/home/y/var/crash/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4194304 -XX:GCLogFileSize=4194304 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/y/logs/yjava_jetty -XX:InitialHeapSize=12884901888 -XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 -XX:MaxHeapSize=12884901888 -XX:MaxNewSize=7730102272 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=4194304 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseFastUnorderedTimeStamps -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
```

Comment: Can You add the details of which Jvm and garbage collector You are using to the question.

Comment: @SilverShroud done!

Comment: Checking the log output, object copy seems to cause the spike. But survivor or old generation size does not seem to increase in these cases(maybe a bug). I would try updated versions of java 8 runtime to see if it behaves the same. You can also try to play with following values to limit the size of eden space -XX:G1NewSizePercent
-XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent

Comment: @SilverShroud I've done some more testing and touching the G1 knobs does not seem to work, switching to CMS did though, latency dropped a lot because Eden Evacuation does not seem to pause with CMS. It does feel a bit backwards to use CMS while G1 is much more modern.

Comment: I think these flags are experimental flags. To be able to use them some other flag has to be set. (look into this If You have missed it)

Comment: While the G1 collector is more modern, the one in JDK8 is not the latest, AFAIK.
In jdk8 CMS is still the best low latency collector, IMHO. There are some other points to be made to your post: 
1, That eden is emptied on GC (nothing moves to S0/S1) is a good thing. GC is more efficient with a large dead set. This is what young gen gc architecture was made for. 
2, On both CMS and G1 the app will pause during scavenge. This is unavoidable. There are later GC:s (zgc, zing) that are pauseless.

Comment: 3, 12 GB eden is _very_ large. Try making it smaller. 4, have you tried using G1 without any flags except max heap? G1 will adjust itself to match the behaviour of your app and usually does a good job of it. Setting many flags you sometimes end up with strange and unexpected behavious.

Comment: This is old, so you probably moved on. Indeed this is mostly impossible in protobuf-java. There's a trick that helps a little bit, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870564/1273080, other than that use https://github.com/HebiRobotics/QuickBuffers. If you can't, good luck! :)